# OnClinetClick inside gridview fires before Enabled property validation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a link button template field inside the gridview. The enabled property has a validation that disables the button based on the value of status field. The linkbutton has an OnClientClick property which displays a confirmation box. If the user confirms, the OnCommand event fires.

> '
>   OnCommand="lnkBtnDeleteItem_Command" ToolTip='Delete Item'
>   Enabled='<%# (Eval("Status") + string.Empty).Equals("5") ? false :
>   true %>'>

The problem is the OnclientClick validation pops up even when the button is disabled - which is done by the Enabled property validation. How do i make the Enabled property validation to fire before onclientClick? or any other alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pop onclick event using code:

```
if (status == 5)
  lbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return !this.disabled;");
else
  lbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return confirm('Are you sure?');");
```